# is it possible to emulate user actions on the site without opening a browser?

Tags: node.js

I don't know if this sounds crazy, but is there such an npm package that allows you to interact with the site for testing without opening a browser?

Comment: depends on how the site works.. you can send requests to your server with `xmlhttprequest` or `node-fetch`.. if it's for browser side emulation(like the html structures) an html parser like `node-html-parser` can be helpful

Comment: How about looking up for DOM mutations when certain methods are invoked? Would that be enough?

Comment: Check out http://zombie.js.org/